The necessity of label encoding for categorical variables already consisting of 0 and 1 (SMOTE, ADASYN)
I have both numerical and categorical explanatory variables, and I want to conduct logistic regression.
My dataset is imbalanced, so I plan to use ADASYN to address this issue.
The categorical explanatory variables are already encoded as 0 and 1, and their data type is 'category',
so I didn't apply additional label encoding.
However, ADASYN generates NaN values for some of these categorical variables.
When I applied label encoding to these explanatory variables (which consist of 0 and 1),
the NaN values did not appear.
What could be the problem?
I thought label encoding was unnecessary since the categorical variables were already encoded as 0 and 1.
However, without label encoding, ADASYN generates NaN samples for some of these categorical variables.
also same for SMOTE

Could you please provide some code to illustrate your issue?
More generally, I think that oversampling may not be neccesary in your problem (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08528), and some code will eneable us to help you better.
